# Creating 2D numpy array from binary file?

Tags: numpy, binaryfiles

I am using the following data set which is a binary file from: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data

Data looks like this:

```
1350423,5,10,10,8,5,5,7,10,1,4

1352848,3,10,7,8,5,8,7,4,1,4

1353092,3,2,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,2

1354840,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2

1354840,5,3,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,2

1355260,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2

1365075,4,1,4,1,2,1,1,1,1,2

1365328,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2

1368267,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2

1368273,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2

1368882,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
```

Binary file has 699 such lines.

I am then using the below code to get the data from binary file saved as 'sample.data' and save it in a  2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    dtype = np.dtype('i8')
    b = np.fromfile('sample.data', dtype=dtype)
    ndata = np.array(b)
    print(ndata.shape)

main()
```

I am looking to get a (699,11) array i.e each row from binary file as numpy row and each element separated by comma as a numpy row's element.

what can I do here to achieve the same ?

Comment: broken link; you need to know information about how this array was stored and would  probably need to  reshape it:  b = b.reshape(699, 11)

Comment: Changed the question to reflect how binary file looks like

Comment: this is textual file, you can use `np.loadtxt('sample.data', delimiter=',', dtype=np.object)`, or it would be better to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for such cases.

Comment: You can't usefully read a number like `1350423` as `int8`, it needs too many bytes and will overflow. There's another datafile you can use, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the file http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/unformatted-data and then did this:

```
ndata = np.genfromtxt('unformatted-data', skip_header=16, delimiter=',')
```

The array `ndata` has shape (699, 11).

Be careful, because there are various groups of data (there are comments in the file that `numpy` is ignoring) in there and it might not make sense to lump them all together.